# C#: Replacing the first plain character in HTML string

Tags: c#, html, string, replace

What I am trying to do is to replace the first character within a HTML string to my own custom style with a new tag. Unfortunately I am unable to do it in a general way to work for all of my examples.

Consider the next possible HTML strings:

```
string str1 = "hello world";
string str2 = "<p><div>hello</div> world <div>some text</div></p>";
string str3 = "<p>hello <span>world</span></p>";
string str4 = "<p><a href="#">h</a>hello world</p>";
string str5 = "<p>hello world <div>some text</div></p>";
```

The results should be:

```
str1 = "<span class=\"my-style\">h</span>ello world";
str2 = "<p><div><span class=\"my-style\">h</span>ello</div> world <div>some text</div></p>";
str3 = "<p><span class=\"my-style\">h</span>ello <span>world</span></p>";
str4 = "<p><a href="#'><span class=\"my-style\">h</span></a>hello world</p>";
str5 = "<p><span class=\"my-style\">h</span>ello world <div>some text</div></p>";
```

In the results the 'h' letter has been changed to `<span class=\"my-style\">h</span>`

Could anyone please help me with that ?

Comment: Post your HtmlAgilityPack code so people can help. If you are doing string replace / regEx - it may be better to keep it private to avoid down-votes.

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov i didn't quite understand you.

Comment: Did you consider doing it with javascript? It would be a lot easier.

Comment: Please write code for me is not exactly welcome on SO as you've probably noticed. It is expected that answer contains code you tried to perform the task. So since normal way of dealing with HTML is to use HtmlAgilityPack (or maybe other parser of you choice) I'm suggesting you to show sample that uses it. Indeed your code may be using string.Replace or Regex.Replace, but such code usually frowned upon when dealing with HTML - so in this case you may just try to deal with code yourself (instead of getting downvotes first) and close the question.

Comment: @shay__ I prefer doing it in C# (though I believe that if you manage to do it in JS it's quite easy to change it to C#)

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov I understand, the code I have posted is part of my code, since all of my attempts were quite straight-forward I don't really have such code to add, I didn't use HtmlAgilityPack

Comment: You could extract the innerhtml using the method provided [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/477066/Extract-inner-text-from-HTML-using-Regex). Then change it to your liking and replace the original innervalue for the edited one.

Comment: Hint - use HtmlAgilityPack. Parsing HTML for first text node is non-trivial task - no point doing it yourself unless it is for educational purposes. Note that JavaScript samples will not help you because they all have HTML in DOM form and not a string...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following two methods. First extracts the first word of the innertext:

```
private static string ExtractHtmlInnerTextFirstWord(string htmlText)
{
    //Match any Html tag (opening or closing tags) 
    // followed by any successive whitespaces
    //consider the Html text as a single line

    Regex regex = new Regex("(<.*?>\\s*)+", RegexOptions.Singleline);

    // replace all html tags (and consequtive whitespaces) by spaces
    // trim the first and last space

    string resultText = regex.Replace(htmlText, " ").Trim().Split(' ').FirstOrDefault();

    return resultText;
}
```

Note: credits to http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/477066/Extract-inner-text-from-HTML-using-Regex

Then, you replace the first word with the edited value (which also calls the `ExtractHtmlInnerTextFirstWord`.

```
private static string ReplaceHtmlInnerText(string htmlText)
{
    // Get first word.
    string firstWord = ExtractHtmlInnerTextFirstWord(htmlText);

    // Add span around first character of first word.
    string replacedFirstWord = firstWord.Replace(firstWord[0].ToString(), "<span class=\"my-style\">" + firstWord[0] +"</span>");

    // Replace only first occurrence of word.
    var regex = new Regex(Regex.Escape(firstWord));
    string replacedText = regex.Replace(htmlText, replacedFirstWord, 1);

    return replacedText;
}
```

You can call the method using the following:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string str1 = "hello world";
    string str2 = "<p><div>hello</div> world <div>some text</div></p>";
    Console.WriteLine("Original: " + str1);
    Console.WriteLine("Edited value: " + ReplaceHtmlInnerText(str1));
    Console.WriteLine("Original: " + str2);
    Console.WriteLine("Edited value: " + ReplaceHtmlInnerText(str2));
    Console.Read();
}
```

Output:

```
Original: hello world 
Edited value: <span class="my-style">h</span>ello world 
Original: <p><div>hello</div> world <div>some text</div></p> 
Edited value: <p><div><span class="my-style">h</span>ello</div> world <div>some text</div></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

:first-letter selector may help you to do this using CSS.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstletter.asp